# Infer function template arguments in return statement from the function's return type

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I have a function that returns a template class.
In this function, the return statement calls a template function that creates an instance of the template class. Is it possible, in the following situation, to infer the template function's template arguments?

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

template <class T, class U>
auto make(T&& t) -> std::variant<T, U> {
    return std::variant<T, U>{ std::forward<T>(t) };
}

auto foo() -> std::variant<int, char> {
    return make<int, char>(42);  // return make(42); instead?
}
```

Comment: Let's assume there's a way to do what you want; how would the language figure out that `U` should be `char` in your example?

Comment: By implicitly using `foo`'s return type template arguments in `make`'s function call. The type information is there.

Comment: And, if `make<int, any_other_type>` is specialised to return a `variant<int, char>`, how would you expect the compiler to deduce whether to call `make<int, char>` or `make<int, any_other_type>`?    You see, that's the problem - in general, the compiler cannot assume all specialisations of your `make()` have distinct return types.    If it can't assume that, it can't deduce the return type of `foo()` in the manner you expect.   That's why it is necessary to tell it.

Comment: @Peter And yet, return types can be used in type deduction in some other contexts. Like `std::variant<int, char> (*make_f)(int&&) = make; return make_f(42);` works.

Comment: Does your use case allow instead deducing the function’s return type from the call to `make<…>`?

Comment: @aschepler - in that case, all the information the compiler needs to deduce the type is in the definition of `make_f`  (the information to the left of the `=`).   That isn't true in the case the OP is asking for.    Incidentally, in the OP's example, if the types of arguments of the function depended on both `T` and `U`, the compiler could infer the types `U` and `V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `make` wrap whatever you give it in an object that has a conversion to the required specialization of `std::variant`:

```
template<typename T>
struct make {
    make(T &&x) : x(x) { }
    T &x;
    template<typename... Us>
    operator std::variant<T, Us...>() {
        return std::forward<T>(x);
    }
};
template<typename T>
make(T&&) -> make<T>;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this technique often doesn't play very nicely in user-facing APIs because there's no mechanism to prevent the user from using `auto` and ending up with an intermediate type.

Comment: Or just `std::variant<Us...>`, so that the argument doesn't need to be the first type in the variant. It would then just wrap the `variant(T&&)` requirement that conversion to one type wins overload resolution over the others.

Comment: @aschepler That's what I did at first, but the OP's code has the same behavior and perhaps there's a reason for it.

Comment: Okay, but the OP `make` also supports only exactly two types.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is pretty horrible (and relies on `foo` not being overloaded):

```
template<class F> using return_t=…;  // exercise
template<class R> using make_t=
  R (&)(std::variant_alternative_t<0,R>&&);
template<auto &F>
constexpr make_t<return_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(F)>>>
  make_for=make;

auto foo() -> std::variant<int, char> {
    return make_for<foo>(42);
}
```

A small amount of generalization of `std::variant_alternative_t` would of course be possible, but since you have to name `make` explicitly in the template (because function templates and overload sets can’t be template arguments), it’s not clear what that would add.